# WebRTC Video in Flutter local application not working on some devices

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I have created a WebRTC based video call application using Flutter, and set it up with a TURN server written in GO. Everything works fine locally, as well as across networks with *some* computers, however for the vast majority of computers that try to use this local application, the TURN server handshake succeeds, but the video does not work. I haven't been able to figure out what could cause this, since for most uses the video works.